# Question with MLE

Tags: time-series, self-study, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

I'm having some problems with this question, and was hoping someone here could help.

> Let $X_1,\ldots,X_2$ be $n$ determinations of a physical constant
>   $\theta$. Consider the model
>
> $X_i = \theta + e_i,$   $~~~~~~i = 1,...n$
>
> and assume
>
> $e_i = \alpha e_{i-1} + \beta e_{i-2} + \epsilon_i$, $~~~~i =
>  1,\ldots,n$, $~~~e_0=0, e_{-1}=0$
>
> with $\epsilon_i$'s i.i.d standard normal, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$
>   are known constants. What is the maximum likelihood estimate of
>   $\theta$? Carefully justify each step of your derivation.

Answer (score 5):

See whether you can justify the steps of this strategy and carry it out.

1. The vector $(X_i)$ has a multivariate Normal distribution.  (Proof?)  Therefore we need to find the parameters of this distribution, which are its mean and covariance matrix.
2. All the $X_i$ have a common expectation of $\theta$ so the multivariate mean is the vector $\mu = (\theta, \theta, \ldots, \theta)$.
3. The covariance matrix $\Sigma$ can be computed using the recurrence relation for the $e_i$.  To do this, express the $(i, i+j)$ entry in this matrix for $j\ge 0$ (which is Cov$(X_i,X_{i+j})$) in terms of the $(i, i+j-2)$ and $(i,i+j-1)$ entries and solve the resulting linear recurrence relations.  The solution, as a function of $i$ and $j$, will otherwise depend *only* on the known values $\alpha$ and $\beta$

   (You might want to start by working out formulas for the diagonal entries Var$(X_i,X_i)$.)
4. The likelihood of the data $\mathrm{X} = (X_1, X_2, \ldots)$ is the probability density of a multivariate Normal distribution with parameters $(\mu,\Sigma)$ evaluated at $\mathrm{X}$, *considered as a function of the unknown* $\theta$, but depending explicitly on whatever values $\alpha$ and $\beta$ might be known to have.
5. The log likelihood is a quadratic function of $\theta$.  Using a convenient formula for the locations of minima of quadratic functions (aka vertices of parabolas), write down the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks for that. I spent some time trying to work it out, but I'm still having trouble with step (3). I tried following your suggestions but, I can't seem to be able to write down the covariance matrix. Any help would be much appreciated!